# Magento 2.3.2 Developer mode error in setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2.3.2, setup-di-compile, command

I am using the Magento 2.3.2 version. When I run the "setup:di:compile" command then Can't remove directory: directory is not empty error occurred.

[image]

I have also set the permission of the generated folder but no luck.

Please tell me how to do this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try completely deleting the contents of the `generated/code` folder

Comment: I have tried but same errror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give permission to **generated** folder from Terminal. Use below command

```
chmod -R -v 777 generated
```

After that run compile command and let me know if it's works.

Comment: This solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Remove generated folder with - sudo rm -rf generated/
Then execute -

1) bin/magento s:up

2) bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

3) bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I have tried but no any luck

Comment: @HardikMakwana, Happy coding help each other...!